# Refresh combo box in Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, combobox

HI,

This question has been asked a lot on the web but all of them seems to be confused with windows forms and asp.net  forms so I had to finally come here for answer.

I have a Main form (a window form) in VB.NET which has a Combo Box to display a list of countries.  A sub form activated from a "Button" on the Main form allows users to add Countries to their list. But After Adding a new entry the Combo Box on the Main form does not show the update (while it is still open). I have to exit the main form and relaunch it to see the update.

The populate function in shown below. I call this method after adding new countries but still; not good. I have used Invalidate function of combo box but of no use as well.

Any Help is appreciated. Thanks

```
Public Sub PopulateCountry()
Dim rsLocal As New ADODB.Recordset
    Try

      Dim sSQLCommand As String
      Me.CountryList.Items.Clear()
      'get the list of countries from the local database
      sSQLCommand = " SELECT *  FROM CountryList order by CountryDesc"
      rsLocal.Open(sSQLCommand, cnn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
      'Display All the  countries
      While rsLocal.EOF = False

        Dim Country As New modGV.cbItem
        Country .ID = rsLocal.Fields("CountryID").Value
        Country.name = rsLocal.Fields("Country Desc").Value.ToString.Trim
        Me.CountryList.Items.Add(Country)
        rsLocal.MoveNext()
      End While

      rsLocal.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception    

      Debug.WriteLine("PopulateCountry: exception occurred " & ex.Description)

    Finally
      If rsLocal.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        rsLocal.Close()
      End If      
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: No worries I got it. The Populate method is in the Main form class and the code to insert new country is in the CountyList class.

Before I was creating anew instance of Main form class in the CountyList Class but what I had to do was pass the current instance of Main from class to CountyList class and then call the Populate function using the passed instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use object.refresh

http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18646

Comment: does not work yet. There is no Data Source attached to it. I am populating it manually.